# android: how to know passed parameter needed from android xml

Tags: android, parameter-passing, android-xml

I follow a tutorial then I got this code on my android xml layout :

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
**android:onClick="onClick"**
android:text="Button" />
```

then on .java file there are method :

```
public void **onClick(View view)**{
   //...something...
}
```

So I dont have any idea why "view" parameter sent from xml,
at least I need to know what parameter needed by xml.
There are many code like that, and android documentation doesn't well explained about this

Answer (score 1):

**view is Instance of your View(In Your case Button).And it Check like view.getId();....**

If you use onClick method For  more than one Button .....

```
switch(view.getId()){
case R.id.btn1: 
     //click on btn1
case R.id.btn2:
     //click on btn2
case R.id.btn3:
     //click on btn3   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

View parameter is you button which is clicked or any other layout or view which has registered onclick is clicked.
It is used when suppose you have two buttons which would be clicked.So in onlclik you can check whether view== button1 or button2 etc

Answer (score 0):

Any object there would be a view..

so when onClick(View view) happen here, this view variable (of type View) can be used for further coding (just after //something ).. 
That passed parameter is useful as "identifier" what that Click event happened on, on which view on screen.. Consider views here not just views like in real life, but *any element in UI, like TextView, Button, EditText, ImageView..*

So it is very useful for code to know where that click happened, or what user actually clicked on..

[here is some reference for deeper understanding of Views](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html):

> This class represents the basic building block for user interface
>   components. A View occupies a rectangular area on the screen and is
>   responsible for drawing and event handling. View is the base class for
>   widgets, which are used to create interactive UI components (buttons,
>   text fields, etc.).

Hope it helped..

Answer (score 0):

When you implements an OnClickListener you must have to override onClick(View view) method, where Parameter view is nothing but the actual view on which you have clicked.

e.g. Let say you have 2 buttons in your layout, and you applied click event on both. Now your activity class is implementing OnClickListener, then you need to check the clicked view this way:

`public void onClick(View view){`

```
  if (view == button1){
      // Do Something on Button1 click
  } else if (view == button1){
      // Do Something on Button1 click
  }
```

}

I hope this will help.